# Problem with libqt4-dev. Messed up dependencies

Tags: application-development, dependencies, ubuntu-touch, qt-creator

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and tried to update ubuntu-sdk but today it wasn't possible without adding phablet-team/tools PPA as described here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_1_-_Desktop_Setup
I did that and updated ubuntu-sdk. After that when I was trying to start Qt Creator I got following error:

[image: http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/72d93a81eef1d525afc5f82d7cc61790.png]

So I decided removing and installing ubuntu-sdk again might be a good idea.
Unfortunately it was not. When installing I got error messages. And if I try to fix it via USC I have following:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 189383 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libqt4-dev (from .../libqt4-dev_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt4-dev_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/uic3', which is also in package qtchooser 0.0.1~git20121229.g8f08405-0ubuntu1~precise1~test5
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqt4-dev_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtwebkit-dev:
 libqtwebkit-dev depends on libqt4-dev (>= 4:4.8.0~); however:
  Package libqt4-dev is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqtwebkit-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl-dev:
 libqt4-opengl-dev depends on libqt4-dev (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Package libqt4-dev is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo apt-get install libbotan-1.10-0

will help

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I could not install or uninstall anything. Always get message about error and suggestion to run `sudo apt-get install -f` Finally I ended up reinstalling my machine.